# CSS Stylesheet Partially Loading on IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a WordPress site that I recently moved from one domain to another (using my host's dotnetpanel).  When it went live on the new domain, it does not show up correctly in Internet Explorer.  Previously, it worked well in all browsers.  Specifically, it seems like parts of the stylesheet are just being ignored.  It works fine on all browsers tested except IE.

Comment: Can you nail it down, *which* portion of *which* stylesheet doesn't get applied?

Comment: i haven't checked your website, but I remember I've had similar problem in drupal. IE only supports up to 32 individual CSS files. Just letting you know.

Comment: @user194076 - this is a good thing to point out, and in fact, it's a max of 31 stylesheets (and a max of 1023 styles in each). It does catch people out. But I don't think it's the issue in this case; the site linked in the question has relatively few stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in and testing to see if it fixes your problem. What parts look like they're being ignored?

Comment: Adding the html5shiv gets the background image to be shown for the whole page, but the element sizing issues and other background issues are unfortunately still present.

Comment: @Nick I believe your problem is with the slider because that's not appearing in the IE version.

Comment: @Nick Also, did you reset your styles? That could also be causing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset styles"?

Comment: When I view the source with Chrome's Inspect Element Tool, it shows everything that should be in the <head> tag as being inside the <body> tag and the actual body is nowhere to be found.  I think this might be the cause of the issue but I'm still not sure what the issue is.

Comment: It may be related to this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blog-page-moves-scripts-into-body-tag http://wordpress.org/support/topic/head-scriptslinks-showing-up-inside-body-tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to reinstall some of your plug-ins?

I guess there are some wrong paths in the database or config-files.

Try to search database by db-admin-tool and all the files with an advanced text-editor with the option to search automatically in all files at the same time.

Comment: I just deactivated all of the plugins on the site and the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the style sheets are applied.

You have `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on the links in the menu, which messes with their size in IE. Remove those styles.

The reason that the gradients doesn't show up is because they are filters, and the elements has to have layout for the filters to apply.

> The object that the filter is applied to must have layout  before the filter effect will display. You can give the object layout by setting the height  or width  property, setting the position  property to absolute, setting the writingMode  property to tb-rl, or setting the contentEditable  property to true.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you give the elements layout, the gradients will show up, for example:

```
.block h2 { width: 100%; }
```